# How to get a substring after certain character

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to extract the company name from an email inside my asp.net mvc web application:-
for exmaple if i have an `email address = myeamil@mycompanyname.com`

to get `Mycompanyname` with first letter capital?
BR

Comment: Surely someone out there has tried to solve this problem before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string address = "myeamil@mycompanyname.com";
string name = address.Split('@')[1].Split('.')[0];
name = name.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1); // Mycompanyname
```

Another option to get name is regular expression:

```
var name = Regex.Match(address, @"@([\w-]+).").Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 5):

To get rid of the @ and everything before that, you would use something like this in your particular case:

```
string test = "myeamil@mycompanyname.com";
            test = test.Substring(test.IndexOf('@')+1, test.IndexOf(".") -(test.IndexOf('@')+1));
            MessageBox.Show(test);
```

And [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/uppercase-first-letter) explains how to make the first letter a capital, which you would use after you strip out the @ and .com parts.

Answer (score 2):

Just another variant

```
var name = new MailAddress("myeamil@mycompanyname.com").Host.Split('.').First();
name = name.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", name.Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string email = "myemail@mycompanyname.com";
int startIndex = email.IndexOf( "@" );
int endIndex = email.IndexOf( ".", startIndex );
string domain = email.SubString( startIndex + 1, endIndex );
string domain = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(domain);
```

That will return **Mycompanyname**